# Retrieve list of cookie in Salesforce

Tags: cookies, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, cart

I have a shopping cart feature in my Salesforce page. I've created a CookieJar class to store the cookie based on this [tutorial](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/storing-form-field-values-with-the-apex-cookie-class) I would like to retrieve a list of cookie. Currently the cart page will only retrieve 1 cookie which contains 1 product. I would like to retrieve all the cookies that I've stored. How do i do that?

APEX CONTROLLER:

```
public PageReference addToCart() {

for(DisplayProducts p : products) {
    if(0 < p.qtyToBuy) {
        //Create an instance of the cookieJar class, passing it the values entered in the fields
        cookieJar c = new cookieJar(p.productid, p.name, String.valueOf(p.qtyToBuy)); 
    }
}
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/cart');
pageRef.setRedirect(true);
return pageRef;

}


public String getCartContents() {
    String msg = '<ul>\n';
     Cookie theCookie;

    theCookie = ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('productid');
    if(theCookie != null)  
    msg +=theCookie.getValue();


    theCookie = ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('productName');
    if(theCookie != null)  
    msg +=theCookie.getValue();

    theCookie = ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('qtyToBuy');
    if(theCookie != null)  
    msg += theCookie.getValue();
}

public class cookieJar {

        public cookieJar(String productid, String productname, String qtyToBuy) {

            Cookie pId = new Cookie('productid', productid,null,315569260,false);
            Cookie pName = new Cookie('productName', productname,null,315569260,false);
            Cookie qty = new Cookie('qtyToBuy', qtyToBuy,null,315569260,false);

            //Set the page cookies using the setCookies() method
            ApexPages.currentPage().setCookies(new Cookie[]{pId, pName, qty});

        }

    }//end cookieJar inner class
}
```

VF CART PAGE:

```
<apex:form >
     <apex:pageBlock title="Your Cart" id="shopping_cart">

      <apex:outputText value="{!cartContents}" escape="false"/>

</apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You already have the code you require in your question:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies()
```

[PageReference.getCookies()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_PageReference_getCookies.htm) will return you a map from the keys to the Cookie.

```
Map<String, System.Cookie[]> cookieMap =  
for(string cookieKey : cookieMap.keySet()) {
    System.debug('Cookie Key: ' + cookieKey + ' value ' + 
        cookieMap.get(cookieKey).getValue());
}
```

Incidentally, the [Salesforce Stackexchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) site is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions.

Comment: Hi @daniel thank you for your reply. I tried you method, however the Cookie will only retrieve the current selection. It won't display all the products that has been selected. Furthermore, the same product is repeated thrice on the page.

Comment: Hi @daniel is there a way for me to append all the cookies that I've set into one list. As for now, it will only retrieve the newly added cookie.